# GPL question : web application using Imagick and GhostScript => Which would be the final licence?

Tags: licensing

I am a bit confusing and I need your help to undertand my problem.

I have developed a web application (PHP, JQuery) for one of my customer.

Recently, my customer ask me to add a new feature permitting PDF to JPG conversion.

After web browsing, I have discovered that iMagick ([Apache licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License)) PHP extension with GhostScript ([GPL licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)) is the only solution.

But, as my customer want to sell the web application to others companies, I have to use non-GPL licences.

By the way, this feature is OPTIONAL and the final user must download and install manually iMagick and GhostScript if he his interesting by using the PDF conversion.

Is there someone to tell me if the fact to use Imagick to convert PDF to JPG (and therefore use GhostScript) turns my current proprietary licence to GPL?

And what about if I don't use Imagick but call GhostScript using PHP exec() function?

Is there others non-GPL projects to convert PDF to JPG that I could use with PHP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not quite a dupe but see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/non-gpl-alternative-to-ghostscript?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I read that, but I can't figure it out if calling GhostScript through a PHP extension is "communicate with separate GhostScript process via a pipe"

Comment: But as I understand, if I call unmodified GPL software using PHP function exec(), it will create a separate process to execute the task without returning objects to use. Therefore, it is allowed.

Comment: Yes, a pipe just means you read/write to the other app as if it was on the commandline, if this isn't possible in PHP you write the pdf to a tmp file, call GS with exec() and read the resulting jpg file

Comment: This is exactly what I do. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: the best (and likely only) way to ensure you're not pulled into a GPL morass is to ensure that you don't have any GPL dependencies anywhere at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Ghostsript as a separate process either reading/writing files or directly streaming stdin-stdout.   Then your app isn't a derived work of ghostscript which can be freely distributed alongside your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand well, exec PHP function execute a separate process, so it is allowed. Do you know if using a PHP extension to call GPL software is allowed?

Comment: The correct answer is - that's upto the judge when you go to court! But the reality  has been that if you call a GPL app unmodified as a separate process then that's fine - if the user is still free to replace the GPL app. If you wanted to "play nicely" you could have a config option which would allow calling any other pdf->jpg command line app